# Set Certain Columns that should not be included

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**Using Laravel Query Builder**.

I have many columns in my 'user' table. 
I want not to include only one column.

For example: I will not include **'col1'**

Instead of using like this.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->lists('col2', 'col3', 'col4'...);
```

I want something like this.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->NotInLists('col1');
```

How do I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have user model use

```
User::select('column1','column2')->get();
```

OR

```
DB::table('users')->select('column1','column2')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $hidden = array('col1');
    // ...
}
```

Add the column names in the `$hidden` array that you don't want to show up in the result. Now you may `query` like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$users = User::all();
```

The columns added in the `$hidden` array won't be available in the result. Also you may manually select `columns` like this:

```
$users = User::select('col2','col3')->get();
$users = DB::table('users')->select('col2','col3')->get();
```